# Splitting the data in machine learning

Tags: python, dataset

In machine learning, why do we need to split the data? And why do we set the test size to 0.3 or 0.2 (usually)? Can we set the size to 1? and also why is 85% considered good for the accuracy?

PS. I'm a beginner please be easy on me ^^

Answer (score 0):

So why do we split the data? We need some way to determine how well our classifier performs. One way to do this is use the same data for training and testing. If we do this, though, we have no way of telling if our model is overfitting, where our model just memorizes features of our training set instead of learning some underlying representation. Instead we hold-out some data for testing that our model never sees and can be evaluated on. Sometimes we even split data into 3 parts - training, validation (test set while we're still choosing the parameters of our model), and testing (for tuned model).

The test size is just the fraction of our data in the test set. If you set your test size to 1, that's your entire dataset, and there's nothing left to train on.

Why is 85% good for accuracy? Just a heuristic. Say you're doing a classification task, picking the most frequent class gives you at least 50% accuracy. We might be skeptical if a model has 100% accuracy because humans don't do that well, and your training data probably isn't 100% accurate, so 100% accuracy might indicate something's going wrong, like an overfit model.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question. I'd recommend you do some courses before asking questions here as literally every good course on machine learning will explain this. I recommend Andrew Ng's courses, you can find them on Coursera but the videos are also on youtube.

To answer your question more directly, you use a train set to teach your model how to classify data, and you test your model with a "dev" or "test" set to see how well it has learned on new unseen data.

Think of it like teaching a kid to add by telling them 1+4=5 and 5+3=8 and 2+7=9. If you then ask the kid "what's 1+4", you want to know if they have learned to add, and not just memorised the examples that you gave.

This video in particular answers the question of what size test/train sets to use.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1waHlpKiNyY